# That's what has him disappointed

Tags: phrase-usage, present-perfect

Is the sentence "That's what has him disappointed" equal to "That's what has disappointed him"?

Is it the present perfect in the "That's what has him disappointed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the present perfect in the "That's what has him disappointed"?

No it isn't. An equally grammatical statement would be:

"That's what has him shaking his head in disappointment."

As you can see there is no past participle in the latter.

> Is the sentence "That's what has him disappointed" equal to "That's
>   what has disappointed him"?

It has roughly the same meaning but it is not an inversion.

It means: "That is what has him in a state of disappointment."

---

A paraphrase may help:

That's what has him disappointed = That is the thing that maintains him in a state of disappointment.